Integration along a path is well defined.
I am new to complex analysis, and get confused about the definition of integration along paths.
Given a smooth curve $\gamma$ with parametrized by $\gamma_1: [a,b] \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}, $It is defined as $\int_a^b f(\gamma_1(u)) \gamma_1^{\prime}(u) \mathrm{d} u
$
I would like to show the defnition is independent of the choice of parametrization. $\gamma_2 \circ \phi = \gamma_1$. Here $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ belong to the same equivalence class of parametrizations.
There exists a proof in the book by Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi
$\int_a^b f(\gamma_1(u)) \gamma_1^{\prime}(u) \mathrm{d} u
=\int_a^b f(\gamma_2(\phi(u))) \gamma_2^{\prime}(\phi(u)) \phi^{\prime}(u) \mathrm{d} u$ and then it stated that by the chain rule and change of variables formula, we get the result.
I know he tries to substitute like $t=\phi(u)$ and then get the result. But I only know this process is valid for real functions and the proof is given by using the Newton-Leibniz primitive. There also exists a version using primitive to prove a theorem but only after checking the integration is well defined.

If $g=u+iv$ where $u,v$ are real functions, then $$\int_a^bg(t)dt:=\int_a^bu(t)dt+i\int_a^bv(t)dt.$$
